# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=7.0.0.0, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: .net, azure, function, .net-6.0, nuget-package

I am getting below issue in my function app while debugging in local. Please let me know the issue here ! I think there is a bug from the packacges that i have used.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified

I have added below packages

Comment: "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.0" />
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10" />
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.10" />
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="7.0.0" />
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="7.0.0" />
    "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    "System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.5" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have this issue before.
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions installs some of your packages implicitly, remove things like Microsoft.Extensions.Options. Somehow, the Functions are using an older version (6.0.0 iirc) and are leading to some problems this way.